# pl/sql: stored procedure table or view does not exist

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql

I have two tables CUSTOMER and ORDER from the same tablespace.

If I do `select * from CUTOMER.date a left join ORDER.date b on a.id = b.id`, it will work fine.

If I create a stored procedure like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE aProc(prc OUT Sys_Refcursor)
AS
BEGIN
OPEN prc for select * from CUTOMER.date a left join ORDER.date b on a.id = b.id;
END aProc;
```

It will cause error:

> Table or view does not exist.

If I change the procedure name aProc to CUSTOMER.aProc, only ORDER will cause the table does not exist error.

I also tried AUTHID CURRENT_USER, which doesn't work.

Is there any way I can get both tables?

Comment: Can you post the exact query rather a mocked one.

Comment: on which schema is the procedure been created?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by adjusting the levels of packages, thank you for your attention anyways